# How do you include a Graphviz diagram in Python docs with epydoc?

Tags: python, graphviz, dot, epydoc

[Epydoc documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/epydoc.html#graph-directives) says that you can include a Graphviz diagram in your source code by means of the `dotgraph` directive.

However, if try this:

```
#: .. dotgraph:: Test
#:    graph name {
#:      a -- b -- c;
#:      b -- d;
#:    }
```

What I get is simply an error saying `Unknown directive type "dotgraph"`.
I use the latest `epydoc` (v3.0.1) and `dot` is installed correctly in my system.

How can I make `epydoc` produce the diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Check the epydoc configuration file for the "dotpath:" variable.  Make sure that this variable is set to your filesystem path to the dot executable.

Comment: OK, thanks. I set it to /usr/bin (I am on Ubuntu). That has helped a bit: I don't get the error anymore. However, I don't get the diagram either... :-(